# Calling a function of one Contract inside another Contract not workig correctly?

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a problem like this. I am very new to solidity. I have tried an example that I was found by a Google Search in the remix editor. But I was unable to get any output like in the example.[This is the tutorial that I followed](https://zupzup.org/smart-contract-interaction/)

According to the tutorial, I create a two solidity file called Callee.sol and caller.sol. Here I am providing that callee.sol contract.

```
contract Callee {
    uint[] public values;

    function getValue(uint initial) returns(uint) {
        return initial + 150;
    }
    function storeValue(uint value) {
        values.push(value);
    }
    function getValues() returns(uint) {
        return values.length;
    }
}
```

And my caller.sol is looked like this.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract Caller {
    function someAction(address addr) returns(uint) {
        Callee c = Callee(addr);
        return c.getValue(100);
    }

    function storeAction(address addr) returns(uint) {
        Callee c = Callee(addr);
        c.storeValue(100);
        return c.getValues();
    }

    function someUnsafeAction(address addr) {
        addr.call(bytes4(keccak256("storeValue(uint256)")), 100);
    }
}

contract Callee {
    function getValue(uint initialValue) returns(uint);
    function storeValue(uint value);
    function getValues() returns(uint);
}
```

Firstly I deployed The callee.sol contract
[image: When I deployed it this the way it looks]

Then I deployed the contract call caller.sol.

[image: after the deployment of the second contract]

Then I copy the address of callee contract and call the function of caller contract like this but it gave a nothing as output.

[image: when function calling]

[image]

Can someone help me to make this work? Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you make a proper screen shot or copy/paste for the function call?
Do you put the address between quotes?

Comment: works as expected, it does return it internally. I think you are expecting some value to be seen. You can assign a public variable to see what was returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you click on that green tick mark in left side of the console it will open a table that all the information for the transaction is inside it and you can read it, as you can see in this image " https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkJ7e.jpg " . it's transaction information for "someaction" function.